# Unable to deposit ETH to simplest-possible contract

Tags: contract-development

```
contract MyContract{


}
```

With Ethereum-wallet on the Morden testnet, if I try to send or deposit ETH, it gives an exception.

In browser-solidity, if I call the fallback function with `msg.value = 10`, it also throws an exception.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to mark the fallback function `()` with the `payable` modifier for the contract to receive ethers.

[image]

From [Solidity Version 0.4.0](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.0):

> This release deliberately breaks backwards compatibility mostly to enforce some safety features. The most important change is that **you have to explicitly specify if functions can receive ether via the payable modifier**. Furthermore, more situations cause exceptions to be thrown.
>
> Minimal changes to be made for upgrade:
>
> - **Add payable to all functions that want to receive Ether (including the constructor and the fallback function)**.
> - Change _ to _; in modifiers.
> - Add version pragma to each file: pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
>
> ...