# Gas not enough and not able to run functions

Tags: mist, gas, contract-deployment, gas-limit

I am a new comer to the Ethereum and I am writing a piece of smart contract for my project. I used Win 10 and Mist 0.8.8 with the testnet that started with "R".

The contract code has the functions of  changing the state and some modifier, however, after I launched the contract, I am not able to run any functions of it. The following errors show up. Thank you so much!!!

[image]
[image]

The contract code is show below: Thank you so much!

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;
contract FairTrade {

    /* Variables */
    address public creater;
    address public trader;
    address public framer;
    address public preieumHandler;

    /* State handling */
    enum State { Paying, Transporting, Received, Completed }
    State public state;

    /* Contructor */
    function FairTrade(address _trader, address _framer, address _preieumHandler,
      uint _price, uint _quantity) {
        creater = msg.sender;
        trader = _trader;
        framer = _framer;
        preieumHandler = _preieumHandler;

    }

    /* Modifiers */    
    modifier onlyFramer {
        if (msg.sender != framer) throw ; else _;
    }

    modifier onlyTrader {
        if (msg.sender != trader) throw; else _;
    }

    modifier inState(State s) {
        if (state != s) throw; else _;
    }

    modifier notInState(State s) {
        if (state == s) throw; else _;
    }

    /* Functions */    
    function completedPaid() onlyTrader {
        state = State.Transporting;
    }    

    function receivedGood() inState(State.Transporting) onlyFramer {
        state = State.Received;
    }

    function paid() inState(State.Received) {
        state = State.Completed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Testnet has the name **Ropsten**.

From the raw data `0x295b4e17` in your first image, you are trying to execute the `paid()` function.

I checked each of the function signatures in the `geth` command line and the following signature matched:

```
> web3.sha3("paid()").substring(0, 10)
"0x295b4e17"
```

This `paid()` function has the modifier `inState(State.Received)` and this modifier will throw an error is the current `state` variable is NOT `State.Received`.

The warning you are being show is because Mist simulates the call you are attempting to execute and has determined that the call the `paid()` will fail as the current `state` variable is not set to `State.Received`.

To test out your functionality, you could either:

1. Add other function(s) to move your workflow state to `State.Received`; or
2. Remove the `inState(State.Received)` modifier from the `paid()` function.

I would suggest firstly trying 2. above so you can determine whether you can execute the `paid()` function successfully. Once you have confirmed that the `paid()` function without the modifier executes successfully, create the other require functions to move your contract `state` to `State.Received` when `paid()` with your modifier will work.

---

### Update Responding To Comment Below

**Q**: Should I use uint to be the type of variable to record ehter send?

**A**: `uint` (which is `uint256`) is suitable for recording the number of ethers.

**Q**: When I send 1 Ether to the contract, it shows 1000000000 wai instead.

**A**: 1 ether is 1e18 or 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 weis. In `geth`:

```
> 1e18
1000000000000000000
> web3.fromWei(1e18,"ether")
"1"
> web3.toWei(1,"ether")
"1000000000000000000"
```

**Q**: Finally, I would like to learn the cml to run the contract. Do you have some recommended link for me?

**A**: If `cml` refers to command line, i.e., using the `geth` command line, there are some step-by-step guides at:

- [Deploying the Greeter contract via the geth CLI is not registering in my private blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/deploying-the-greeter-contract-via-the-geth-cli-is-not-registering-in-my-private)
- [Smart Contract different behaviour on testnet vs Solidity Browser](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8951/smart-contract-different-behaviour-on-testnet-vs-solidity-browser)
- [Understanding TokenCreator/OwnedToken example from Solidity documentation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/understanding-tokencreator-ownedtoken-example-from-solidity-documentation)

You may also want to check out Browser Solidity - see [How to call Library Function from a Contract? => [error] The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount. undefined](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/how-to-call-library-function-from-a-contract-error-the-contract-code-could) for an example.

Comment: O my god!! Thank you so much I will try it out once I got the computer. Can I ask you what is the payable modifier in the contract? I have seen a lot of contracts have this function to handle translation. Somebody said if we do not have it, once it throw, all the gas will be consumed. Thank so much.

Comment: Any function that is marked payable, including the default function (see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9297/1268) is able to receive ethers sent with the transaction invoking the function. An error will be thrown if you send ethers when calling a function that is not marked payable. This is so you can design contracts where a user cannot accidentally send ethers when it is not required.

Comment: Thank again. Everything is working fine. Should I use `uint` to be the type of variable to record ehter send? When I send 1 Ether to the contract, it shows 1000000000 wai instead. Finally, I would like to learn the cml to run the contract. Do you have some recommended link for me? Many thanks.

Comment: See updated answer for response to the questions in your comment above.